# Mobile Broadband C# interface to manage Profiles

Tags: c#, mobile, com, broadband

I am trying to use the C# interface to the mobile broadband API.  The code below compiles and intellisense displays all of the COM methods, but the code does not execute correctly.

```
MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
IMbnConnectionProfile conProfile = (IMbnConnectionProfile)mbnInfMgr;

string xmlBuff = conProfile.GetProfileXmlData();
```

The following error is produced:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interfacetype
'MbnApi.IMbnConnectionProfile'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
for the interface with IID '{DCBBBAB6-2010-4BBB-AAEE-338E368AF6FA}' failed
due to the following error:
No such interface supported(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

Microsoft lists the calls as below:

```
IMbnConnectionProfile Interface Method C# Signature

Delete              public void Delete();
GetProfileXmlData   public string GetProfileXmlData();
UpdateProfile       public void UpdateProfile( string strProfile);
```

It looks as if I need to specify the interface but can't seem to find out how to do this.

Can any one show me how to do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling [IMbnInterfaceManager::GetInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [IMbnInterfaceManager::GetInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  methods.

E.g.

```
MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
IMbnInterfaceManager infManager = (IMbnInterfaceManager)mbnInfMgr;

//obtain the IMbnInterface passing interfaceID
string interfaceID = “{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}”;

IMbnInterface mbnInterface= infMgr.GetInterface(interfaceID);

MbnConnectionProfileManager mbnProfMgr = new MbnConnectionProfileManager();
IMbnConnectionProfileManager profileManager = 
                                  (IMbnConnectionProfileManager)mbnProfMgr;

IMbnConnectionProfile[] profArr = 
(IMbnConnectionProfile[])profileManager.GetConnectionProfiles(mbnInterface);
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I will have a go now using your solution - Many Thanks for your time to respond to my problems.

Comment: I have been able to read the profiles now from each interface to xml documents but I am unable to edit/amend, an exception is thrown with no details on the code below.

Comment: XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(profArr[0].GetProfileXmlData());

            xdoc.Add(new XComment("Modified by System")); Do you have any idea as to why this is - Thanks